# pulumi up fails with error: unable to open bucket file

Tags: pulumi

Running `pulumi up` fails with:

```
error: unable to open bucket file:///var/folders/mz/path_to_dir: stat /var/folders/mz/path_to_dir: no such file or directory

error: unable to open bucket file:///var/folders/mz/path_to_another_dir: stat /var/folders/mz/path_to_another_dir: no such file or directory
```

Checking the file system shows that `/var/folders/mz/path_to_dir` and `/var/folders/mz/path_to_another_dir` exist and have the correct owner and permissions setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that the issue was with a corrupted `~/.pulumi/credentials.json` file.

Valid `credentials.json` file has the following structure:

```json
{
    "current": "https://api.pulumi.com",
    "accessTokens": {
        "https://api.pulumi.com": "YOUR_TOKEN"
    },
    "accounts": {
        "https://api.pulumi.com": {
            "accessToken": "YOUR_TOKEN",
            "username": "YOUR_USERNAME",
            "organizations": [
                "YOUR_ORG"
            ],
            "lastValidatedAt": "SOME_DATE"
        }
    }
}
```

In my case the file content was:

```json
{
    "current": "https://api.pulumi.com",
    "accessTokens": {
        "file:///var/folders/mz/path_to_dir": "file:///var/folders/mz/path_to_dir",
        "file:///var/folders/mz/path_to_another_dir": "file:///var/folders/mz/path_to_another_dir"
    },
    "accounts": {
        "https://api.pulumi.com": {
            "accessToken": "YOUR_TOKEN",
            "username": "YOUR_USERNAME",
            "organizations": [
                "YOUR_ORG"
            ],
            "lastValidatedAt": "SOME_DATE"
        }
    }
}
```

Fixing the `credentials.json` file to its expected structure fixed the issue.